# reshape fails with total size of new array must be unchanged even for correct dimenions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter

Here is an example code that I am trying

```
def normalizeImages(data): 
    x = np.shape(data)[0]
    y = np.shape(data)[1]
    z = np.shape(data)[2]
    w = np.shape(data)[3]
    darray = np.array(data) 
    dflat = darray.flatten() 
    mindflat = min(dflat)
    maxdflat = max(dflat)
    for x in range(0, len(dflat)): 
        dflat[x] = (dflat[x] - mindflat)/(maxdflat - mindflat)* 255 
    arraynd = np.reshape(dflat, (x, y, z, w))
    return arraynd.tolist();
X_valid = normalizeImages(X_valid)
```

it fails with

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-33-eb3d96398060> in <module>()
     19     return arraynd.tolist();
     20 
---> 21 X_valid = normalizeImages(X_valid)
     22 #X_train = normalizeImages(X_train)
     23 #X_test = normalizeImages(X_test)

<ipython-input-33-eb3d96398060> in normalizeImages(data)
     16     for x in range(0, len(dflat)):
     17         dflat[x] = (dflat[x] - mindflat)/(maxdflat - mindflat)* 255
---> 18     arraynd = np.reshape(dflat, (x, y, z, w))
     19     return arraynd.tolist();
     20 

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in reshape(a, newshape, order)
    222     except AttributeError:
    223         return _wrapit(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
--> 224     return reshape(newshape, order=order)
    225 
    226 

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

The input X_valid is a 4 dimensional list of shape (4410, 32, 32, 3). Can anyone explain why this fails and how to fix?

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but why do you flatten your data - and why do you use a for loop?

Comment: You are changing the value of variable `x` in your loop. Here `for x in range(0,len(dflat)):`

Comment: I am new to python so I could only come with a loop & flatten. Thanks for the cool approach!. I have been really looking this for long but never realized the obvious usage of x again in the code. Thanks for catching the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the value of variable `x` in your loop. Do this instead; you don't even need a loop for this

```
def normalizeImages(data):
    darray = np.array(data) 
    x, y, z, w = np.shape(darray)
    dflat = darray.flatten() 
    mindflat = min(dflat)
    maxdflat = max(dflat)
    dflat = (dflat - mindflat)/(maxdflat - mindflat) * 255 
    return dflat.reshape(x, y, z, w).tolist()
```

You don't even need to reshape your data

```
def normalizeImages(data):
    darray = np.array(data) 
    mind, maxd = darray.min(), darray.max()
    darray = (darray - mind)/(maxd - mind) * 255 
    return darray.tolist()
```